# signals used by the timeout command

Tags: linux, bash, timeout, signals

I want to run a program with a timeout. I'm doing it by using the `timeout` command like this

```
timeout 5 path/to/program
```

`program` is using time-related signals: blocking, unblocking and raising SIGALRM and SIGVTALRM. I don't know how `timeout` works, but I guess it also uses time signals. Should I be worried about signals from `program` interfere with `timeout` and vice versa?

Comment: What's the output of `timeout --version` ? Modern versions of timeout should work fine, because they run the target program in a separate process and don't set any timers in that process.

Comment: `timeout (GNU coreutils) 8.25` Is this modern enough?

Comment: I looked at the 8.25 source, and it doesn't set timers in the target program. Another way to check this on Linux is to run `timeout 10 cat /proc/self/timers`.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

By default, `timeout` will send a `SIGTERM` (unless you change it with `-s`). Therefore, you shouldn't see any conflict with any other signals.

FYI, If a program is exited by the timeout, then it will have a return value of `124`. You can force a kill (if it doesn't die gracefully) using `-k SECONDS` which will then give it a return value of `137`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't entirely answer my question. I suspect that `timeout` internal logic uses `ALRM` signal, and this may interfere with my program. Should I be concerned about **that**?